# Need to deploy Node.js docker image to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using bitbucket-pipeline

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, bitbucket-pipelines

I need to deploy a Node.js docker image from dockerhub to Elastic Beanstalk. I am building the image and then pushing it to the hub.docker.com now I want to deploy the image from hub.docker.com to the AWS Elastic Beanstalk using bitbucket-pipeline. The pipline is not building the image and pushing it to hub.docker.com, I want now to deploy the image using the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following as the top line for the bitbucket-pipeline.yml:

```
image: node # or whatever is the image name you built on docker hub
```

In the scripts section, then you need to run the docker-compose commands to build and push the image.